# Culture route parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, localization

I hace an angular site. In all routes I have a culture route parameter, called :culture. So the URL's look like:

```
 http://domain.eu/en/start
 http://domain.eu/nl/start
```

Now, when the user goes to the site, he can log in using an external provider (via Identity Server), and on succesful login he is redirected back to the root of the site: http://domain.eu.

The problem I have is that I want to redirect to the correct start page depending on the culture that was saved in the profile settings of the user. For example, user X logged in and has dutch as his default language.

In my app-routing.module.ts I have:

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'en/start',
     pathMatch: 'full',
    },
 ];
```

...and I was wondering how I can redirect to the correct culture instead of the hardcoded 'en/start'. Can I use a variable to construct the redirection path or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use route paramters for this. see the example below.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
       {
         path: '',
         redirectTo: ':culture/start',
         pathMatch: 'full',
        },
     ];
```

After setting the route parameters, just redirect as you would usually do.

[See documentation for details](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the path:'' to an MyRedirectComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
   const locale = 'en'; // TODO your logic
   this.router.navigate(['/' locale + '/start']);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Guard and navigate to route with `router.navigate`